# MediaWiki Table of Contents (ToC) FileTree

Tags: mediawiki, wiki, mediawiki-extensions

I would like to turn the standard Media Wiki ToC to a FileTree structure.
Where you can expand and contract each section.
I want to support unlimited numbers of levels.
A Expand All and Collapase All link would also be nice.

The name of the MediaWiki Extention and a list of URLs (sites)
that implement this type of TreeList for MediaWiki's ToC
so I can read the code, would be very helpful.

Here are example pages that show FileTree structures,
but I don't think they apply to Media Wiki ToC.
http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Template:Category_tree_all
    The following is 5 levels deep.
     Films of Australia?
        The Adventures of Priscilla, Queen of the Desert?
            Stephan Elliott?
                A Few Best Men?
                    A Few Best Men premiere in Sydney?
http://risdpedia.net/index.php/Category:Materials
    The following is 3 levels deep.
    Category:Screen Printing
         Category:Screen Printing Ink
            Category:Fabric Screen Printing Ink
http://wiki.team-mediaportal.com/Wiki_Help/4_Contribute_to_Wiki/Collapsible_Lists%2F%2FTrees
http://test.wikipedia.org/wiki/User%3aKrinkle/CollapsingTestpageMw

Here are MediaWiki Extensions that may do the trick,
but I can't seem to make them work.
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension_Matrix
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TocTree
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Treeview
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Semantic_TreeView
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TreeAndMenu
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aTag_extensions

Here are some resources that mention this type of TreeList for MediaWiki.
But there are no answers for them yet.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20490034/treeview-not-working-on-sidebar-in-mediawiki

Comment: You write that you have found some extensions that might do the job  “but I can't seem to make them work”. What exactly is the problem? What happens when you try, for instance, `Extension:TocTree`?

Comment: I installed Extension:TocTree and it automatically put plus signs [+] next to the first section of the ToC. But the other sections are left untouched. I'm trying to figure out how to do that. Does anyone know how to do that. I couldn't find any examples of Extension:TocTree Googling around.

Comment: The following link http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Wikivoyage:TOC mentions "[+] expand and [-] collapse is from m:Extension:TocTree and settable in user Preferences > Misc." Does anyone know how to get to "user Preferences > Misc.?

Answer (score 0):

I figure out where User Preferences > Misc is located.
Special:Preferences#mw-prefsection-misc